# dynamic scroll bar division with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

im trying to have a dynamic scroll bar with ajax in it, meaning i try and update the division with the scroll bar via ajax, im having a little trouble with this, im using a sample scroll bar i downloaded called Tiny Scrollbar: http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/
you can have a preview of mine here : http://www.luminusconsult.com/apps/testing/index.html

this is what i have in the index page...

```
     <div id="reloaded">
       <div id="scrollbar1">
         <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb">
           <div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
             <div class="viewport">
                <div class="overview">
                   ....

                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
            });
        </script>
```

and when i try and reload the "reloaded" division with ajax...

```
    <div id="scrollbar1">
     <div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb">
       <div class="end">      </div></div></div></div>
         <div class="viewport">
           <div class="overview">
             ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();   
            });
    </script>
```

is there any way i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the tinyscrollbar update method in the success callback of your ajax request.

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar_update();
```